# Assigning values with bitwise and operator

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, pseudocode, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I realize this is pretty trivial stuff, but I can't get my head wrapped around it.

Let's say that I was working with [this message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nvUY.png) This is a 3 word message with 16 bits per word. If I were trying to write pseudocode making these variable assignments, would this be correct:

```
var1 = (word 1) & 0x7FFF

tmp1 = (word 1 >> 15) & 0x0001
tmp2 = (word 2 & 0x3FFF) << 14
var2 = tmp1 + tmp2    

tmp1 = (word 2 >> 14) & 0x0003
tmp2 = (word 3 & 0x7FFF) << 15
var3 = tmp1 + tmp2
```

Comment: Depends what you want to do. Should bit 15 from word 1 stay at the bit 15 place then you shouldn't shift it back to bit 0. But again what is your goal?

Comment: @broch What I want is for each variable to have the following attributes:

var1: 15 bit field, found on word 1, LSB bit position 0, MSB bit position 14
var2: 15 bit field, found on words 1 and 2, LSB bit position 15 of word 1, MSB bit position 13 of word 2
var3: 17 bit word, found on words 2 and 3, LSB bit position 14 word 7, MSB bit position 14 of word 3

Is this what you mean when you ask what my goal is? Ultimately, I just need to assign these the data in that message to these three variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't put the bits from `word2` at the correct position in `var2`, nor the bits from `word3` at the correct position in `var3`, illustrated:

```
0 is a 0 bit,
1 comes from word1
2 comes from word2
3 comes from word3
var1 =     0111 1111 1111 1111 (good)
var2 = ... 2200 0000 0000 0001 (not good)
var3 = ... 3000 0000 0000 0022 (not good)
```

There shouldn't be large stretches of zeroes in the middle.

The extra zeroes are there because the shifts to the left are much too large. It should be:

```
var1 = (word 1) & 0x7FFF

tmp1 = (word 1 >> 15) & 0x0001
tmp2 = (word 2 & 0x3FFF) << 1
var2 = tmp1 + tmp2    

tmp1 = (word 2 >> 14) & 0x0003
tmp2 = (word 3 & 0x7FFF) << 2
var3 = tmp1 + tmp2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So the problem is with the left shift-- I should be shifting by the amount of bits of the desired variable in the previous word.

Comment: @synchh yes exactly, or in more complicated cases in general (for example maybe if a variable is spread over 3 words) it would be "the number of bits that came before it"

Comment: Thanks, one last thing. The number of bits that came before it, going back to the word boundary, or to the previous field?

Comment: @synchh going back all the way to the start of the variable (otherwise the shift count would periodically "reset", and make bits "collide" on top of each other)